# SearchFieldError - Cannot search with field "body". Please add index.SearchField('body') to Page.search_fields

Tags: django, wagtail, wagtail-snippet, wagtail-search

I have a elasticsearch backend (7.14.0) and wagtail (2.14.1) and I want to include a fulltext-search at the body field of my page. When search something in frontend, I get

```
SearchFieldError at /search/
Cannot search with field "body". Please add index.SearchField('body') to 
Page.search_fields.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://my.site/search/?query=impres
Django Version: 3.2.4
Exception Type: SearchFieldError
Exception Value:    
Cannot search with field "body". Please add index.SearchField('body') to         
Page.search_fields.
Exception Location: /var/www/vhosts/my.site/dev4/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/search/backends/base.py, line 163, in check
Python Executable:  /var/www/vhosts/my.site/dev4/venv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.9
Python Path:    
['/var/www/vhosts/my.site/dev4/venv/bin',
 '/var/www/vhosts/my.site/dev4/mysite/mysite',
 '/var/www/vhosts/my.site/dev4/mysite',
 '/var/www/vhosts/my.site/dev4',
 '/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts',
 '/usr/lib/python36.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/var/www/vhosts/my.site/dev4/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 23 Aug 2021 05:24:18 +0000
```

my views.py:

```
from django.core.paginator import EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger, Paginator
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse

from wagtail.core.models import Page
from wagtail.search.models import Query




def search(request):
    search_query = request.GET.get('query', None)
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)

    # Search
    if search_query:
        #search_results = Page.objects.live().search(search_query)
        # exclude some search results
        search_results = Page.objects.live()\
        .exclude(title='Sie sind nun ausgeloggt.')\
        .exclude(title='Sie sind nun eingeloggt.')\
        .exclude(title='Passwort erfolgreich geändert.')\
        .search(search_query, fields=["title", "body"])

        query = Query.get(search_query)

        # Record hit
        query.add_hit()
    else:
        search_results = Page.objects.none()

    # Pagination
    paginator = Paginator(search_results, 10)
    try:
        search_results = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        search_results = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        search_results = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return TemplateResponse(request, 'search/search.html', {
        'search_query': search_query,
        'search_results': search_results,
    })
```

my models.py:

```
from django.db import models

from wagtail.core.models import Page
from wagtail.core.fields import RichTextField
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel

from wagtail.search import index


class HomePage(Page):
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('body', classname="full"),
    ]

    # Search index configuration

    search_fields = Page.search_fields + [ # Inherit search_fields from Page
        index.SearchField('body'),
    ]
```

So I already *added index.SearchField('body') to Page.search_fields* and can't find any type-o's.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure but have you tried running `./manage.py update_index`, see https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/topics/search/indexing.html#the-update-index-command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `fields=["title", "body"]` on the search query doesn't work here, because your search query is being run on the basic `Page` model (which is the right thing to do if you want your search to cover all page types) - here the `body` field is specific to the `HomePage` model, and so it isn't recognised more generally.

Typically the set of fields is going to vary from one page type to another, and you'd only include `fields=[...]` on a search if you're looking for something specific within one particular page type:

```
EventPage.objects.search('london', fields=['location'])
```

For a general-purpose search, you should leave out the `fields=[...]` argument when searching - it will then search across all fields that have been named as SearchFields in all page types. You *should* keep the `index.SearchField('body')` line in place on the HomePage definition, and make sure you've re-run `./manage.py update_index` since adding it.